# how to serve custom image url in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

**I have to give values from view to** `image-url` **like the** `name` **is the value from view :**

**This is my code :**

```
<img src="{% static "covapp/img/{{name}}jpg" %}" width="120" height="90"></img>
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: It is also *not* clear exactly *what* you want to achieve.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i am sorry for this ..next time whenever i will ask a question i will upload the code not the image ..plz vote up my question

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. But it is simply "not (really) done" to use images of code, for the reasons mentioned in the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove**  `{% static “covapp/img/“{{name}}”.jpg” %}` **and  give absolute path of your source image:-**

---

```
src="covapp/img/{{name}}.jpg" 
<img src="covapp/img/{{name}}.jpg" width="120" height="90"></img>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

In your view

```
def your_view(request):
    context = {}
    .
    .
    .
    context['name'] = value_you want_to_use
    return render(request, url_to_template, context)
```

Now in your template, you can use the value as

```
{{name}}
```

Comment: GETTING ERROR CONTEXT NOT DEFINED

Comment: @AshutoshAnand Do it now.

Comment: Update your question with your view, and some more code, what error you are facing now ?